# Create objects with association hierarchy using sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Using sequelize for nodejs, create a hierarchy of object, 3 levels in my case. Model1 belongs to Model2 and Model2 belongs to Model3. When I call create, Model1 and model 2 objects get created but I have not clue how to Model3 created in the database (postgres).

I tried include Model2 in Model1 creation which solved the problem of creating Model2. But I have no clue how to include the creation of Model3 through model2.

Model1-> Has many Model2 -> has many Model3

```
module.exports = {
    create(req, res) {
        return Model1.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            description: req.body.description,
            status: 0,
            Model2s: req.body.model2s,
        },
            {
                include: Model2
            }
        )
```

Now Model2 rows are getting created but I am unable to get Model3 row created.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a frivolous question or nobody has an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer was at the end of Sequelize Associations document page but as marshal's law requires, right at the end of the long document.

```
`return Product.create({
  title: 'Chair',
  user: {
    firstName: 'Mick',
    lastName: 'Broadstone',
    addresses: [{
      type: 'home',
      line1: '100 Main St.',
      city: 'Austin',
      state: 'TX',
      zip: '78704'
    }]
  }
}, {
  include: [{
    association: Product.User,
    include: [ User.Addresses ]
  }]
});`
```

The include statement at the end are not models but associations: In my case

```
`association: Model1.hasMany(Model2),
include: [Model2.hasMany(Model3)]`
```

Hopefully this helps more people out there.